# problem when i apt get update "precise/main armhf Packages 404 Not Found"

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager, architecture

I try a restore my sorce list, change my server updates to main.
But i still have the same problem.

It all started when i try to instal the nvidia cuda toolkit.

I fallow the guide to install the cuda toolkit
I paste this code on terminal:

$ echo "foreign-architecture armhf" >> /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
$ sudo apt-get update

then the errors began to occur

[here is my link of that have the terminal errors](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By_TmPekm-9UaUtLMDJSR0ZfZ1k/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the line:
"foreign-architecture armhf"
in file  "/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch".

I found CUDA can work without adding armhf.

Maybe this is aim to support Tegra or just a mistake of the CUDA guide.